# Taking natural log of exponential

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have the equation:

$$R=R_0e^{bx}$$

I'm given a table with values for $x$ and $R$, and asked to take natural logs of both sides and use a graph to find $b$.

So I think you rearrange the equation into the form $y=mx+c$, input the gradient and intercept after graphing the values of $x$ and $R$.

Here's what I've done so far:

$$\ln(R)=\ln(R_0e^{bx})\\ \ln(R)=\ln(R_0)+\ln(e^{bx})\\ \ln(R)=bx\,\ln(e)+\ln(R_0)\\ \ln(R)=bx+\ln(R_0)$$

So in this last line, is $\ln(R)$ the $y$, $bx$ the $mx$ term, and $\ln(R_0)$ the $c$ term?

Comment: why should this be wrong?

Comment: $$\ln(R)=\ln(R_0)+bx$$ is right, if all variables are positive!

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

If you have to rewrite your equation **in terms of** $\ln(x)$ and $\ln(R)$, as you mentioned in the title, this is the method:

$\ln(R)=\ln(R_0e^{bx})\\\ln(R)=\ln(R_0)+\ln(e^{bx})\\\ln(R)=\ln(R_0)+b\cdot e^{\ln(x)}$

$\to Y=b \cdot e^X+c$

where $Y=\ln(R)$, $X=\ln(x)$ and $c=\ln(R_0)$

Otherwise, your solution is ok. You are looking for $b$ so don't worry about other things as long as your solution is right and it is. You just need to find the slope of the line, that is equal to $b$.

Comment: I think we should thake X=x.

Comment: @gimusi The question is vague I believe. But with any methods, as he is looking for $b$, then there would be no difference.

Comment: There is difference, if you need to interpolate the dat according to the initial equation taking the log both sides then X=x.

Comment: Ah ok you are referring to $Y=b \cdot e^X+c$, sorry I was referring to the expression proposed in the OP. Anyway if you have the data as x value why consider $\log x$? I think that in this case it is better to refer directly to the x values without take the log.

Comment: @gimusi I agree with you that your method is easier, and also mentioned in my answer there's no actual difference and both are correct. I inferred that he **has to** rewrite it in terms of $X=\ln{x}$ and $Y=\ln{R}$ maybe I inferred incorrectly. The question seems vague to me a little.

Comment: I'm very confused. In the practice questions we were told that relationships between data could be of the form $y=kx^n$ or $y=ka^x$. I've assumed my original equation was the latter.
From my graph of ln(R) against x (not ln(x)) I have a negative value for the gradient, which is the bx part of the equation above? Do I take this value in exponential form?. In the practice questions I had two logs on the right hand side and it was easy to write both as powers of 10 where they were in the form y=mx+c

Comment: @Paddington: Yes, it is in the form of $y=ka^x$. "From my graph of ln(R) against x..., which is the $bx$ part of the equation above?" Yes, it is $b$.  Please let me know if you had further questions.

Comment: I will edit my answer as soon as the problem is clarified for me and I understood all your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct, now you need to plot your data $\ln(R)=bx+\ln(R_0)$ as a line of equation $y=mx+c$ assuming

- $y=\ln(R)$
- $x=x$
- $c=\ln(R_0)$

and you can find the angular coefficient $m=b$.

For that you can also use numerical methods as least square.